# Curl: Https_proxy and SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable are set at the same time, SSL_CERT_FILE does not take effect

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate

Precondition:
I used squid for https proxy server, local ip is 10.0.4.11, port:8888 use self-certificate myCA2.pem by this command:
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout myCA2.pem  -out myCA2.pem

part of squid.conf:
https_port 8888 cert=./myCA2.pem

Senarios #1:

export HTTPS_PROXY=https://10.0.4.11:8888
curl --proxy-cacert ./myCA2.pem -v https://www.baidu.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZT80.jpg)

result：curl indicates that CA_file follow the parameter, OK

Senarion #2:
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://10.0.4.11:8888
export SSL_CERT_FILE=./myCA2.pem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0hQR.jpg)

result：Failed, curl indicates CAfile don't obey the environment variable

Senarion #3:
export SSL_CERT_FILE=./myCA2.pem

don't add proxy parameter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw0AR.jpg)

add proxy parameter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRYIj.jpg)
When add proxy parameter, it will become default cert path, don't obey the environment variable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.